# ARKit XR is not enabled error though it is enabled

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, arkit

Here, an error is rising while I am building a project in MAC for iPad. I am currently using MARS for the project and there is this issue.

**Please enable the 'ARKit' plugin in 'XR Plug-in Management'.**

**Open Project Setting > XR Plug-in Management > iOS tab and enable ARKit.**

Although ARKit is enabled, the issue still says I have enabled it!

[image: ARKit Selection]

[image: ARKit Error]

I have disabled and again enabled it, I have tried to build it on different projects and tried it on two different editors, but it didn't work at all.

Versions:

Unity Hub: 3.4.2

Unity Editor: 2020.3.47f1, 2021.3.23f1

AR Foundation and ARKit XR Plug-in: 4.2.7

Unity MARS: 1.5.0

XR Plugin Management: 4.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer .
I found its solution on unity documentations where the dev from unity team has mentioned the solution .
It goes as follows....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpBlm.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541, [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)